# ASP.NET MVC with AUTOFAC - Custom Error Messages Disappeared

Tags: asp.net-mvc, autofac

My custom error messages quit working somewhere along the way and I'm getting this error. Any ideas?

Autofac.ComponentNotRegisteredException: The requested service 'controller.error.aspx' has not been registered.

I have never done anything to register them before.

I saw several questions about the custom error messages, but I couldn't find anything else wrong that was mentioned in those responses.

EDIT:
I have tried "On" and "RemoteOnly" in web.config. I have an Error.aspx in the Shared folder. I am using the [ErrorHandler] attribute. This worked for a long time, and probably quit working when I made some changes to the Autofac configuration in Global.asax. The error message about the service not being registered started at the same time the errors quit working. I don't know how to register this with Autofac.

Comment: Hi Leslie - it would help a lot if you post some details about your setup... Do you have custom errors turned on in Web.config? Do you have an ErrorController anywhere? I'm not sure I'll be able to help but someone more knowledgeable in ASP.NET MVC could probably use this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Nicholas Blumhardt for his help on the [Autofac forum](http://groups.google.com/group/autofac) and Ben Hall for his [blog post](http://blog.benhall.me.uk/2009/01/aspnet-mvc-rc1-removing-code-behind.html). I had to add some attributes to the page tag in web.config and an mvc tag in the controls section. I don't know why the behavior of the app changed, because this information was never in web.config. But it worked!

```
<pages
  pageParserFilterType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewTypeParserFilter, System.Web.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
  pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage, System.Web.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
  userControlBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl, System.Web.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
  <controls>
    <add tagPrefix="mvc" namespace="System.Web.Mvc" assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  </controls>
</pages>
```

EDIT: Thinking about this more, I think the error page must have stopped working when I copied the MVC DLLs into my project. I had to do a DLL deployment of MVC with this app because I can't install MVC on the server.